# How to make a page-specific title in Dancer templates?

Tags: perl, template-toolkit, dancer

I have a standard Perl Dancer app, using Template::Toolkit as rendering engine, with two routes:

```
get '/' => sub {
    template 'index';
};

get '/foo' => sub {
    template 'foo';
};
```

My `views/templates/main.tt` contains the line:

```
<title><%= title %></title>
```

I want the value of title var be "My Site" on page '/', and "Foo - My Site" on page '/foo'.

I know I can put these values in the controller file, like this:

```
    template 'index', { title => 'My Site' };
```

but I want to specify them in the corresponding template files, `views/index.tt` and `views/foo.tt`.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Dancer%3a%3aCookbook#TTs-WRAPPER-directive-in-Dancer-META-variables-SETs-) clearly explains how to configure your application to make available in your layout the variables defined in your templates.

For the title tag, you can save yourself the effort to define the title in each template using the variable `template.name`. Maybe something like that:

```
<title>
  <% template.name.match('(\w+).tt').0.ucfirst %> - <% settings.sitename %>
</title>
```

Comment: Well, that's what I get for not reading the documentation more thoroughly :)  Thank you.